# How to prove that the tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius drawn to the point of contact?

Tags: geometry, circles

I've tried drawing a parallel chord to the tangent but then how would you prove that the chord is perpendicular to the radius?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let $O$ be the centre of the circle, let $\ell$ be a tangent line, and let $P$ be the point of tangency.  Suppose that $OP$ is **not** perpendicular to $\ell$. Draw the line through $O$ which is perpendicular to $\ell$. Then this line meets $\ell$ at a point $Q\ne P$.

Note that $Q$ is *outside* the circle. Now consider the triangle $OQP$. This is right-angled at $Q$.  So $OP$ is the hypotenuse of this triangle, and is therefore *bigger* than $OQ$. But this is impossible: since $Q$ is outside the circle, we must have $OP\lt OQ$.

Comment: This relies on the assumption that the hypotenuse is the longest side of a right triangle. This is not always a prerequisite; we may only know that the hypotenuse is opposite the right angle.

Comment: @Jeremiah No, according to Pythagoras’ theorem, the hypotenuse of a right-angled triangle is always the longest side, unless there is one side has a length of zero - but then it’s no longer a triangle.

Comment: @Henryc17 This is actually true even without Pythagoras' theorem, and holds true even in _neutral geometry_ where Pythagoras' theorem doesn't: In any triangle, the sum of two angles is less than two right angles (I.17), so the right angle is the greatest angle; and the greatest side is opposite the greatest angle (I.19).

Comment: This is essentially Euclid's proof (III.18), written superbly into just a few sentences.  Note that it implicitly relies on the (previously proven) theorem that a line can be tangent to a circle at only one point; otherwise, $Q$ could be _on_ the circle without contradiction.

Comment: Pyth theorem is a way to prove :)

Answer (score 9):

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a circle centered at $O$. Let $\ell$ be a line tangent to $\Gamma$ at a point $A$. Suppose the line from $O$ perpendicular to $\ell$ meets $\ell$ at a point $B$. If $B\neq A$, then there exists a point $C$ on $\ell$ on the other side of $B$ from $A$ such that $AB\cong BC$. (This follows from Hilbert's first axiom of congruence for line segments.)

By the side-angle-side theorem, $\triangle OBA\cong\triangle OBC$, and thus $OA\cong OC$. Thus $C\in\Gamma$. But $C\neq A$, a contradiction, since the tangent line $\ell$ can only meet $\Gamma$ at one point by definition of tangency. Thus $B=A$. Thus $\ell\perp OA$.

Answer (score 4):

[image: By using derivatives, slope of tangent at any point is -x/y. Slope of radius is y/x, which is negative reciprocal of slope of tangent. Therefore, angle OAQ is 90 degrees, because, straight lines whose slopes are negative reciprocals of each other are perpendicular]

By using derivatives, slope of tangent at any point is -x/y. Slope of radius is y/x, which is negative reciprocal of slope of tangent. Therefore, angle OAQ is 90 degrees, because, straight lines whose slopes are negative reciprocals of each other are perpendicular

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

The following shows how a chord ( between separate real root intersections  ) become a single real repeated root at tangent point.

Let the circle be $ (x-h)^2 + y^2 = a^2 $. Let it be cut by a straight line through the origin $ y = m x $. There are two roots. For point of tangency there should be a double root or a single coincident root.

Let  $ h^2 = a^2 + T^2, $

$$ x^2(1+m^2) - 2 x h + T^2 = 0 $$

Discriminant $\Delta$ should vanish.

$$ \Delta =0, h^2 = T^2 (1+m^2) $$

The Pythagoras theorem is satisfied with $h$ as hypotenuse, $a$ radius and $T$ length of tangent, sides $a$ and $T$ are perpendicular with:

$$ \tan(\alpha) = m  = a/T , \sin(\alpha) = a/h $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, since the tangent is perpendicular to the radius drawn to the point of contact and the chord is parallel to the tangent, thus the chord is perpendicular to the radius drawn to the point of contact.

Answer (score -1):

Extend the radius to a line $L$ and use reflection symmetry with respect to this line.